# iphone how to create a .pem file for windows server

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

Can anyone please tell me how to create a .pem file for windows server. Please its urgent

Answer (score 0):

Search the site before asking:
[Creating .pem file for APNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1762555/578260)

or maybe here: at "Getting Started with Certs" ?
http://x-cake.ning.com/profiles/blogs/setting-up-a-push-notification

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I did search. They seem to be for linux server. But I need it for windows server. PLease help

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I did search. They seem to be for linux server. But I need it for windows server. PLease help

Comment: edited my answer with an Windows Tutorial for APNS with cert setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked the link. Its for asp .net, I am using php. PLease help.