# APNS Production Certificate Issue

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I am having trouble creating a valid production .pem file for my iOS app's push notifications.  The development version functions perfect, however I suspect the problem lies with my keychain access attempting to pair a development private key with the production certificate.  Could someone verify either way on this?  If so, where would I find a distribution private key?

I've followed pretty much every tutorial and post I could find on here pertaining to APNS production certificate generation, however I've been having the strangest results.

I've attached a picture of my keychain access where the certs are stored.  If "this" looks right, and it should in fact say "Developer" rather than Distribution, Production, etc... I'll add additional information, just point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look right to me. In my keychain access, each certificate has a private key with a different name.

Comment: I didn't think so.  I just don't know why my keychain access is so odd ever since the upgrade to mavericks.  I never had this many problems with certificates before.

Comment: Why not generate the certificate from scratch, following the [official programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW3)?

Comment: I did.  Several times.  I deleted each certificate, re-generated, multiple times.  My keychain access doesn't behave as it should.  Any idea where my distribution private key is stored?  Or how I can retrieve it?

Comment: This means that you have lost your private key for your distribution certificate, you may have to create a new one altogether, try revoking your current certificate and then Create a new Distibution certificate

Answer (score 0):

Your private key is the same both for Development Certificates and for Distribution certificates.

The Main Issue is to check that the APNS Certificate is Valid and is Signed with your private key. Once you verify this you shouldn't have a problem generating your .PEM files You can follow this response for instructions:

[Creating .pem file for APNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762555/creating-pem-file-for-apns)

Hope this helps ;-)