# APN-Node: Error when loading PEM file

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to get [apn-node](https://github.com/argon/node-apn) to push to my devices. The server is hosted on Heroku, so I do not want to commit the file. Also, I do not want to fetch it from a remote server but instead put it in an environment variable.

I already tried the following ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762555/creating-pem-file-for-apns)):
I created and downloaded the certificate from Apple and now have it in my Keychain. I exported it as a `*.p12` file and converted it with `openssl pkcs12 -in dev.p12 -out dev.pem -nodes` into a `*.pem` file.

To set the environment variable, I did `export APN_CERT="$(cat dev.pem)"`. When I print it out in my application it shows the certificate perfectly fine.
However, when I actually send a notification (and node-apn opens the connection) it throws an **`[Error: wrong tag]`**.
This error is emitted by the crypto module:

```
apn Raising error: +4ms [Error: wrong tag] undefined undefined
 apn Error occurred with trace: +1ms Error: wrong tag
  at Object.exports.createCredentials (crypto.js:176:17)
  at Object.exports.connect (tls.js:1344:27)
  at apnSocketLegacy
```

The module also throws a `APN transmission error: moduleInitialisationFailed (Code: 513)`.

I was unable to find any useful information other than that this could be related to the crypto module itself of node itself. That's why I suspect I did something wrong when creating the certificate but thankful for any guiding advice.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this guide](https://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/wiki/HowToCreatePKCS12Certificate) for apns-sharp which actually described how to generate a valid .p12 file.

Still, writing it into an environment variable did not work. My code for reading it is: `new Buffer(certString, 'binary')` but I thought it still was not supplied in a correct format.

The solution for me was to actually read the buffer directly from a file via `fs.readFileSync`.

---

To get the env variable to work you could encode the file via `cat cert.p12 | base64` and load it as such with `new Buffer(certString, 'base64')`. This finally worked for me.

Comment: To make sure your base64 doesn't have newlines use `base64 -w 0`. I ended up with `cat cert.p12 | base64 -w 0 | clipit` to encode it and copy it straight to the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

The preference here would be to use an encrypted p12 stored alongside the applciation and specify a passphrase which you set via an environment variable.

I was unable to replicate your problem using the following script

```
var apn = require("apn");

var token = "<token>; // iPad

var service = new apn.connection({
    cert: process.env.APN_CERT, key: process.env.APN_KEY
});

service.on("connected", function() {
    console.log("Connected");
});

service.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("Standard error", err);
});

function pushNotification() {
    var note = new apn.notification().setAlertText("Hello");

    service.pushNotification(note, token);
    service.shutdown();
}

pushNotification();
```

Run with:

```
$ export APN_CERT=$(cat certificates/cert.pem)
$ export APN_KEY=$(cat certificates/key.pem)
$ node apn-env.js
```

The error you are seeing `"wrong tag"` is from OpenSSL and suggests a parsing error of the data contained within the certificate data itself rather than the data being loaded incorrectly from the env. Loading PEM files from environment variables works correctly

Comment: Alright, I'm interested to see if you can find anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
var apn = require("apn");

var deviceToken = "device token";

var service = new apn.Provider({
    cert: '.path to /cert.pem', key:'pat to ./key.pem'
});

    var note = new apn.Notification();


  note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60; // Expires 1 minute from now.
  note.badge = 3;
  note.sound = "ping.aiff";
  note.alert = " You have a new message";
  note.payload = {'messageFrom': 'Rahul test apn'};
  note.topic = "(Bundle_id).voip";
  note.priority = 10;
  note.pushType = "alert";

  service.send(note, deviceToken).then( (err,result) => {
    if(err) return console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    return console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
  });
```

Load the pem files and run with the tokens