# ios notification Unable to set private key file in laravel

Tags: php, ios, laravel

I'm trying to send ios notification with laravel (use [laravel-push-notification](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification)) but I get this error: 
`Unable to connect: tls://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195: 2 (stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file /certificate/path.pem)`

Here is my config: 
`'appNameIOS' => array(
        'environment' =>'development',
        'certificate' =>'../path.pem',
        'passPhrase'  => 'passPhrase',
        'service'     =>'apns'
    ),`

But after I remove the quotes from `passPhrase` I just getting `HTTP error 500` without any error on response body.

I created `.pem` files from [this site](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/push-notifications-using-ionic-framework) step by step.

NOTE: I'm using MAMP server.

Comment: Most likely your path to 'certificate' in not correct. I would debug that.

Comment: @AngadDubey I enter the certificate path correct in my app. Because if I insert wrong path I get `Certificate ../../PushCert.pem does not exist`. NOTE: I edited the sample path in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the pem certificate was not created correctly. Be sure to export both the private and public key together from the p12 keychain element. Follow indications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762555/creating-pem-file-for-apns).

Comment: Yes. I created pem file again and everything is ok, but I have another problem. When I send notification, `$push->getFeedback();` return empty array. How can I track notification. How can I know the notification was sent or not or if a problem occurs?