# Cannot get push notifications with PEM file

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, pem

I may sound like noob but I faced a problem and not able to find the solution. I searched all over the google and nothing.

Here is the problem.
I have an app that should receive push notifications. Until iOS 10 everything worked perfect, but now I am not able to receive notifications with my PEM file, instead I can receive them with my P12 file, but PHP won't accept P12, so I am stuck.

I have created my pem-s using this thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762555/creating-pem-file-for-apns)

 In my app code is written based on this [link](http://ashishkakkad.com/2016/09/push-notifications-in-ios-10-objective-c/)

One more thing.

I have tested my push notificatoins also using this website http://pushtry.com/ and in case I use PEM file and TEXT mode, I can receive push, but PEM file and JSON mode does not work. P12 works with both.

I don't know what to do. Please helppppp!!!!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the production server and certs?

Comment: for 1000000000%

Comment: Export .p12 file with entering a password. and when generating PEM again enter the password when required.

Comment: Believe me I have done that for 100 times.. it does not work... I am able to receive the push with the same p12 but not able with PEM of the same p12

Comment: Same issue happening with me, I also can not find how to solve

Comment: I also faced the same issue and currently don't have a solution....

Comment: me too, how to solve it?? Anyone?? Pls....

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, hope it will solve your problem.

1. First, use this link: http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/ and follow their instructions , instead of pushtry.com
2. Implement all the methods related to remote notifications and make sure all these are updated.
3. If by mistaken or accidentally your app not enabled notifications for background mode then refer this link: https://www.iphonemanager.org/ios-11-notifications-not-working.html

I have followed these instructions and at my end apns is working.

Comment: for steps 1, I can receive my push via .PEM file that generated earlier. But when I put this .PEM file to server, it does not work, any idea?

Comment: May be there will be server end or backend issue....If you are getting notification via step 1, then there is no issue in pem or code.... You must need to discuss with your backend team